# Windows Speech Recognition for conversations

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, speech-recognition

How can I use Windows Speech Recognition in UWP application for conversations? For now, it recognizes my voice only, but not voice of another speakers in the same conversation. Maybe, does an another API exist for this?

It's my primitive code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

            Init();
        }

        private async void Init()
        {
            //Compile predifined grammar
            SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult result = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

            speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;

            if (speechRecognizer.State == SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
            {
                await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
            }
        }

        private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender,
                                                                        SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Result.Text);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpeechRecognizer` does not specifically recognize a person's voice. It will analyze the current input sound and convert it into text output through the corresponding grammar.

So the ideal conversation scene of `SpeechRecognizer` is that two people are not far from the microphone, speak clearly, and only one person is talking at the same time.

What `SpeechRecognizer` provides is a simple speech recognition service, it does not provide an API to separate the voices of two people and recognize the output separately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe do you know an another API for my purposes?

Comment: Hello, as far as I know, the tool for speech recognition currently provided in UWP is `SpeechRecognizer`, but it only provides basic speech recognition services, and does not have an API to implement the functions you need.

Comment: I need it for recording my conversation in Xbox Party Chat. So I thought I can run UWP service that uses SpeechRecognizer for it.

Comment: I don't need to separate the voices of two people. I mean that SpeechRecognizer doesn't recognize speeches of another people in conversation except my speech..

Comment: Hello, `SpeechRecognizer` also does not provide corresponding functions. `SpeechRecognizer` parses the incoming voice into text, but this does not include the analysis of voice characteristics (this involves voiceprints).